# Who are the creatures that will torture us in hell according to purans?

Tags: garuda-purana, hell

There are many tortures mentioned in purans. So who will torture bad people in hell.

Comment: A quick search in here ,with tags like *yama duta*, Hell, *naraka*, punishment. ,.and you'll find that it's the *yamadutas*, who will carry out the adjuciated judgement , for the sins, on the appropriate hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Nârada said :-- “O Everlasting One! O Muni! Now describe the various actions that lead to these tormenting hells. I like to hear
>    about them in detail.” 2-52. Nârâyana said :-- O Devarsi! He who
>    steals other’s sons, wives, and riches, the wicked fellow is taken to
>    Yama by His messengers. Tied down hard and fast by the terrible
>    messengers of Yama, by the Kâla rope (rope of time), he is taken to
>    the Tâmisra hell, the place of many torments. **There the Yama’s
>    attendants punish him, beat him and threaten him;** and he becomes
>    stupefied, and feels himself very weak, distressed and ultimately
>    faints. He who deceives another’s husband and enjoys his wives; **the
>    Yama’s servants drag him down to Andha Tâmisra hell. There he suffers
>    any amount of pain and suffering.** He loses instantly his eyesight and
>    his brain gets upset. His state resembles that of a tree when its
>    trunk is broken. For this reason the ancient sages called this Andha
>    Tâmisra. He who being subject to “My” and “Mine” quarrels with others
>    and being very much attached, maintains his family, leaves his
>    families here and goes with his bad tendencies to the Raurava hell,
>    very horrible to all. **The animals whom he injured and killed before in
>    this world, assume the form of Ruru animal and torment him in the
>    next.** For this reason, the intelligent knowers of Purâna, call this
>    Raurava. The ancients say, that Ruru is more cruel and ferocious than
>    snakes. These animals live in that hell; hence it is termed
>    Mahâraurava. He who torments others, goes to this hell and these
>    Rurus, the flesh-eaters, spring on his body and bite and eat his
>    flesh. He who cooks other animals and birds, that cruel and ferocious,
>    thus deluded, **is cooked in return on the hot oil in the Kumbhîpâka
>    hell by the Yama Dûtas for thousand years**. He who quarrels with his
>    Pitris and the Brâhmanas, is taken by the Yama Dûtas to the Kâlasûtra
>    hell and there be burnt by the fire and Sun. There that hellish
>    person, being troubled very much, inside and outside by hunger and
>    thirst, sometimes sits, sometimes sleeps, sometimes walks, and
>    sometimes runs hither and thither. O Devarsi! He who transgresses the
>    path of the Vedas in times other than those of calamity and danger and
>    follows other paths even to a trifling distance, **that sinner is taken
>    by Yamadûtas to Asipatra Kânana and there whipped severely**. Not being
>    able to bear that, he runs wildly to and fro and is pierced by the
>    sharpedged Asi leaves on both his sides. His whole body being cut
>    asunder, he cries “Oh! I am killed!”and faints away. Then feeling
>    himself pained very much, he tumbles down at every step. Thus the
>    sinner suffers for violating the path of the Vedas. The King or that
>    royal personage who gives orders of punishment, not approved by
>    Dharma, and hurts or punishes the body of a Brâhmana, the Yama’s
>    servants throw him down into the S’ûkaramukha Hell and grind down his
>    body with great force as a sugarcane is ground down. He then cries
>    aloud bitterly, he gets fainted and becomes stupefied. He is crushed
>    by them and suffers all sorts of pains and miseries. Again he who
>    knows the feelings of others when they are tormented, pains those
>    insects who live on other’s blood as bugs, etc., and who does not
>    realise other’s pains, goes, as a punishment for that fault to the
>    Andhakûpa Hell. **There he is pained by the beasts, birds, deers,
>    reptiles, mosquitoes, bugs, louses, flies and Dandas’ûkas and various
>    other cruel animals**. There he lives in his ugly body and roams like a
>    beast
>
> [*Source - Devi Bhagavtam; Book 8; Chapter 22*](https://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam44.htm)

So, its basically the Yamadutas (servants of Yama) who torment the sinners. Sometimes the sinners are tormented by certain hellish animals too.